# I am not able to write test for this code ..anyone tell me how to do?

Tags: c#, testing

This is the code..

this class has list, method to add project into list

```
public class Project
{
    //for project
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public Project(string id, string name, string startDate, string endDate) => (Id, Name,StartDate, EndDate) = (id, name, startDate, endDate);     
}   

class ABC
 {
    private List<Project> List { get; set; } = new List<Project>(); // List for project

     public List<Project> List
    {
        get { return ProjectList; } 
    }   

   public void AddProject(Project p) // Method for project addition
     {
      if (!List.Any(x => x.Id == p.Id)) // to check project id already not exist
       {
        List.Add(p); // it will add if already not into list
       }            
     }
  }
```

I want to write n-unit test for "AddProject" method

How can I Write Assert.IsNotNull and Assert.Equal to above method

Comment: The code you showed us has no observable behaviour. The item is added to the list, but there is no way to access this list. You will never find out, which items are element of this list.

Comment: I have not uploaded that code..I have already written method to access the List...That is not the issue @SomeBody ..u can tell me test part if u know...

Comment: yeah added now...

Comment: That current code will not compile, please be as precise as you want us to answer

Comment: If you make your list public gettable, any consumer can directly add or remove items from that list without calling your `AddProject()` method. You should change at least the public property type to `IReadOnlyList`.

Comment: But that is not issue for me @Oliver

Comment: What u want??@Sir Rufo

Answer (score 2):

As Somebody mentioned,
there is no way to check that the List was modified - you need some externally visible change to make a useful test.

I see some ideas:

1. Make the list public, with a private set - so you can observe it.
2. Create a getter for a Ireadonlycollection, so you can expose the list but disallow modifying the contents.
3. You could use Internal visibillity too and configurre your project accordingly.

Comment: This is not issue @Christian Sauer

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a full example :**

i have added a new function called **HasPrject** you can use it in any place to check if the list has a specific project.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ABC abc = new ABC();
        Project p = new Project("1");
        abc.AddProject(p);
        Console.WriteLine(abc.HasProject(p));    
    }
}

class ABC
{
    private List<Project> List { get; set; } = new List<Project>();

    public Boolean HasProject(Project p)
    {
        return List.Any(x => x.Id == p.Id);
    }

    public void AddProject(Project p) // Method for project addition
    {
        if (!HasProject(p)) // to check project id already not exist
        {
            List.Add(p); // it will add if already not into list
        }            
    }
}

class Project
{
    public Project(string Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
    public string Id;
}
```

Comment: I fixed your code indentation, and also removed the duplicated `HasProject` function

Comment: i really appreciate it, i didn't noticed that.